# Restrict access to files via svn but be able to commit new files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

**EDIT QUESTION:**

Is it possible to only give the person access to certain files and folders via svn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

There are several ways you can do this.

One is to setup [access controls](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth) on the server, and the setup is surprisingly similar. This works whether you're using Apache httpd as the server or the `svnserver`. These controls give you the ability to set read, (can you do a checkout?) and write (can you commit changes?) to a repository.

You can also use pre-commit hooks ([like this one](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook)) to control commit changes. The idea is that you use the built in authentication to grant read access to users, then use the pre-commit hook to grant commit access. (A pre-commit hook can't control read access since you need to checkout from the repository in order to use a pre-**commit** hook).

Notice that all of this needs to take place on the *server*, so you'll need access to the server in order to set it up. The *control file* of the pre-commit hook I linked to above (which can only really control commit access) can live inside the repository. This means you can change access to making changes without having to be on the server.